# StartCoroutine method is not working in my Unity code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to write a udp client in Unity, and the client called StartSendMes method after receiving the message from the server, but it never entered the coroutine code.The console printed "before StartCoroutine", but never "SendMes Method".This puzzled me now.
There is my code:

```
    public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var length = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        if (clientID < 0)
        {
            if (length > 0)
            {
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
                var id = message.Substring(11);
                Debug.Log($"Client ID: {id}");
                clientID = Int32.Parse(id);
                StartSendMes();
                StartReceive();
            }
            return;
        }
        if (length > 0)
        {
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
            Debug.Log(message);
        }
        StartReceive();
    }

    public void StartSendMes()
    {
        Debug.Log("before StartCoroutine");
        StartCoroutine(SendMes());
    }

    public IEnumerator SendMes()
    {
        Debug.Log("SendMes Method");
        while (true)
        {
            if (isSending)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / tick);
                continue;
            }
            var sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Ball.position.ToString());
            isSending = true;
            curTick++;
            socket.SendTo(sendBuffer, SocketFlags.None, iPEndPoint);
            isSending = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / tick);
        }
    }
```

I wirted a test component which is only include a coroutine methon and called StartCoroutine in Start method, and it works fine.

Comment: And I am sure that the code is a Component, and it's active always be true.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Make sure the gameObject that this script is attched to it, it's active when you call the "StartCoroutine" method and also make sure it is a MonoBehaviour Script.